# Use awk to find first occurrence only of string after a delimiter

Tags: bash, awk

I have a bunch of documents that all have the line, `Account number: 123456789` in various locations.

What I need to do is be able to parse through the files, and find the account number itself. So, `awk` needs to look for `Account number:` and return the string immediately following.

For example, if it was:

```
Account number: 1234567
```

`awk` should return:

```
1234567
```

Once it's found the first occurrence it can stop looking.

But, I'm stumped. What's the right way to do this using `awk`?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

One way:

```
awk -F: '$1=="Account number"{print $2;exit;}' file
```

I assume you want to stop the moment you find the first occurence in the file. If you want to find occurrences in every line of the file, just remove the `exit` .

Answer (score 9):

You can use an `if` to check if `$1` and `$2` equal "Account" and "number:". If they do, then print `$3`:

```
> awk '{if ($1 == "Account" && $2 == "number:") {print $3; exit;}}' input.txt
```

Comment: Exactly how would I do that?

Comment: Why the extra `{}`?  Why not just `awk '$1 == "Account" && $2 == "number:" { print $3; exit }' input.txt`?

Comment: @tianon Actually you can do this: `awk '/^Account number: / { print $3; exit }' FILE`

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer outputs a space in front of the string which forced me to use another approach:

```
awk '/Account number/{print $3; exit}'
```

This solution ignores the `:` separator but works like a charm and is a bit easier to remember IMO.

Answer (score 3):

For such matchings I prefer using `grep` with look-behind:

```
grep -Po '(?<=Account number: )\d+' file
```

or

```
grep -Po 'Account number: \K\d+' file
```

This says: print whatever sequence of digits (`\d+`) appearing after the string `Account number:`.

In the secondcase, `\K` clears the matched string, so that it starts printing after such `\K`.

---

See it in action given a file `file`:

```
Account number: 1234567
but then another Account number: 789
and that's all
```

Let's see how the output looks like:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=Account number: )\d+' file
1234567
789
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `sed -n s///p`:

```
sed -En 's/^Account number: (.+)/\1/p' *.txt | head -n1
```