# use awk to search for multiple terms but return only the first matching term

Tags: awk

I use `awk` in the following command to return app names on my phone:

```sh
aapt dump badging App.apk | awk -F: '/label-uk/ {print $2}'
```

The problem is, I found that some of them use different labels like "label-en-GB" instead.
So after some research, I thought I should add a pipe like so:

```sh
awk -F: '/label-uk|label-en-gb/ {print $2}'
```

But this returns duplicates for the apps that contain both terms, then I tried with two pipes, like so:

```sh
awk -F: '/label-uk/ || /label-en-gb/ {print $2}'
```

Both commands work, but both show duplicates.

Can `awk` return only the first matching term instead of both?

Thank you!

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use awk to find first occurrence only of string after a delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331259/use-awk-to-find-first-occurrence-only-of-string-after-a-delimiter)

Comment: [Again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66084273/1745001) you're asking for help to parse the output of a command but not showing us the output of the command so the answers you get could be completely inappropriate even if they do produce the output you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the following, it will exit after first match (see the additional: `exit`)

```
... | awk -F: '/label-uk|label-en-gb/ {print $2; exit}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
aapt dump badging App.apk | awk -F: '/label-uk|label-en-gb/ && fnd !=1 {print $2;fnd=1}'
```

Set a variable fnd to 1 when we print the first instance and then only print when fnd is not equal to 1.